# Reversed y-data and y-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am pretty new to D3. I created a scatter plot that looks almost correct. Somehow the y axis and data is reversed:

[image]

The reason for this is probably the coordinate system, whose origin (0,0) is in the upper left corner. Does anyone know how I can quickly fix the problem?

```
const svg = d3.select('#chart');
const height = +svg.attr('height');
const width  = +svg.attr('width');
const margin = {top: 20, left: 100, bottom: 300, right: 20};
const inner_width = width - margin.left - margin.right;
const inner_height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const render = data =>
{
const y_scale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.GDP_2017)]) //Gross Domestic Product
    .range([0, inner_height])
    .nice();

const x_scale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.HDI_2017)]) //Human Development Index
    .range([0, inner_width])
    .nice();

const graphic = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)

graphic.append('g').call(d3.axisLeft(y_scale));

graphic.append('g')
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x_scale))
    .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${inner_height})`); 

graphic.selectAll('circle')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('circle')
        .attr('cy', d => y_scale(d.GDP_2017))
        .attr('cx', d => x_scale(d.HDI_2017))
        .attr('r', 3);
};
```

Comment: Try `.attr('cy', d => inner_height - y_scale(d.GDP_2017))`. Just like you stated above, the origin is at the top left. You then have to adjust for the margin.